# How do I copy the elements of a 2D array onto a 1D vector?

Tags: c++

So i keep trying to transfer the elements but it keeps giving me repeated elements, it fails to properly copy the 2D array onto a 1D vector

```
    // This was one of my attempts
    vector<int> rando(int rowsize, int columnsize)
    {
        int elements = rowsize*columnsize;
        vector<int> x(elements);
        int matrix[100][100];

        for(int i = 0; i < rowsize; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < columnsize; j++)
                    {
                        srand((int)time(0));
                        matrix[i][j]= -10 + rand() % 21;
                        for(int n=0; n < elements; n++)
                        x[n]=matrix[i][j];
                    }

    // Ive also tried this

        for(int n=0; n < elements; n++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < rowsize; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < columnsize; j++)
                {
                    x[n]=matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

                }

        return x;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using the `elements` loop?  Your i/j loops already correctly walk the matrix.

Comment: because i want to assign the elements of the array onto a vector of size elements.  i want to put all the array elements into a single dimensional vector.

Comment: Ah, but that's not what you're doing.  You're setting every element in the array to whatever value `i, j` points to.  What you want to do is transform the i and j values into an index: `int pos = i * rowsize + j;  x[pos] = matrix[i][j];`

Comment: Use `<random>`, don't seed at the beginning of every iteration of the inner loop, you're in trouble if `rowsize != columnsize != 100`, and do `x[i * columnsize + j] = matrix[i][j]`

Comment: You should only call `srand` once

Answer (score 1):

THe general copy should loop through the 2 dimensions, and just increment the target index at each iteration (no third nested loop):

```
    int n=0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < rowsize; i++)
    {
         for(int j = 0; j < columnsize; j++)
         {
             ...
             x[n++]=matrix[i][j];   // not in an additional for loop !! 
         }
    } // end of initialisation of matrix
```

If your matrix is a 2D array (i.e. contiguous elements) you can also take the following shortcut using `<algorithm>`:

```
copy (reinterpret_cast<int*>(matrix), reinterpret_cast<int*>(matrix)+elements, x.begin());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to store data into the matrix first and copy it into the vector afterwards? Use the vector from the start.

```
std::vector<int> rando(std::size_t rowsize, std::size_t columnsize)
{
    std::vector<int> v(rowsize*columnsize);
    std::mt19937 mt{std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rand_dist(-10, 10);
    for (auto & e : v) e = rand_dist(mt);
    return v;
}
```

If you want to transfer data from a matrix into a vector you must calculate the proper index or just increment a single variable as Thomas Matthews suggests.

```
constexpr std::size_t n = 100, m = 100;
int matrix[n][m];
// do stuff with matrix 
std::vector<int> v(n*m);
for (std::size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
  for (std::size_t j=0; j<m; ++j)
  {
     v[i*m + j] = matrix[i][j];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unsigned int destination_index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < rowsize; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < columnsize; j++)
    {
        x[destination_index++]=matrix[i][j];
    }
}
```

The destination index is incremented after each assignment to a new slot.
No need for a 3rd loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to use two loops.

For example

```
srand((int)time(0));

for(int i = 0; i < rowsize; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < columnsize; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j]= -10 + rand() % 21;
        x[i * columnsize + j] = matrix[i][j];
    }
}
```

In general if you have a two-dimensional array and want to copy `nRows` and `nCols` of each row elements in a vector then you can use standard algorithm `std::copy` declared in header `<algorithm>`

For example

```
auto it = x.begin();

for ( int i = 0; i < nRows; i++ ) 
{
    it = std::copy( matrix[i], matrix[i] + nCols, it ); 
}
```